# What's done on Zos Chanuka?

Tags: minhag, chanuka

I know people call the last day of *Chanuka* "*Zos Chanuka*" (taken from [*Bamidbar* 7:84](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%96_%D7%A4%D7%93), read on that day). How is it specially commemorated if at all? I've heard it is, but know no details.

I'm not asking [*why* it is special, which has already been asked](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4530), but *how*. What do people do special on that day?

Comment: Seudas Mashiach?

Comment: It follows the general pattern of significance of day being directly proportional to length of Torah reading.

Comment: By the way, the yekkes call the eighth day of Chanukah, Chanukas HaMizbeach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nitey Gavriel Chanukah ([Perek 56](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46444&st=&pgnum=334)) quotes the custom to wish one another "gmar chasima tova" and that of having a special meal.