# Earliest source for "Zos Chanuka"

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, chanuka, provenance

What is the earliest source/authority to ascribe special significance to the eighth day of Chanuka?

Comment: very related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4530/8775 and also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22776/whats-done-on-zos-chanuka?rq=1. Note that the answers indicate it is a Hassidic belief.

Comment: not the BneYssachar?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46444&st=&pgnum=334&hilite=

Comment: http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=12055; http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=7162

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to all of the above commenters.

A Bar Ilan search shows that the earliest mention of the day known as "Zos Chanukah" is in the Sefer Haminhagim of R' Isaac Tyrnau, 14th-15th century (Minhagim Chodesh Teves).  It doesn't specifically mention forgiveness, but it does make it sound like it is some sort of significant day ([here's](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Y7xhAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP78&dq=%22%D7%96%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi58uCGl-PeAhWE1VkKHTaGDUYQ6AEISzAG#v=onepage&q=%22%D7%96%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94%22&f=false) a link to a 1591 printing of it):

> ובספר תורה שנייה קורין למפטיר בנשיא גמליאל וכו' [ומקצת בהעלותך] עד כן עשה את המנורה, כי יום שמיני הוא **זאת חנוכה**.

and later:

> חתונה ומילה היו בשבת שני דחנוכה שהוא **זאת חנוכה**

Various later sources ascribing it Kabbalistic significance have been found (see links in comments), but they only begin in the 16th century.